# google map +boostrap modal not work resize

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi guys I have the following problem. The google map is not dimensioned against that point. Here is the code I've written so far. I do not know why but this function `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`does not work if you put it in click event

```
$(function() {
var map;

$('.check-in').click(function(e) {

    var coordX = $(this).data('x'),
            coordY = $(this).data('y');

    initialize(coordX, coordY);

});


function initialize(x, y) {  
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
    var map_options = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}
```

});

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, the map is contained within a bootstrap modal and is not resizing once the modal is shown/displayed.

To do this, you need to trigger the google maps resize event on the modal's 'shown' event. For Bootsrap v3, the following should work. For v2, use 'shown' instead of 'shown.bs.modal'

```
$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem.
I solve it whit show the map in  
I think there problem whit js files conflict